# What regexp do I need to find a string in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, file-get-contents

I am trying to find the string:

sd_src:"https://video.fhyd6-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t42.9040-2/10000000_2379299605422668_4104252399957311488_n.mp4?_nc_cat=1&efg=eyJybHIiOjY0OCwicmxhIjoyODQ5LCJ2ZW5jb2RlX3RhZyI6InN2ZV9zZCJ9&rl=648&vabr=360&_nc_ht=video.fhyd6-1.fna&oh=2f555df6a07d18aa1f472d972dab0114&oe=5C80FCA5

in the source code of the link https://www.facebook.com/PeinadosFacilesRapido/videos/399225660865821/ and to print that in PHP.

Look at the code you will understand:

```
<?php
$sourceurl = file_get_contents('https://www.facebook.com/PeinadosFacilesRapido/videos/399225660865821/');
preg_match('REGEXP', $sourceurl, $link);
echo $link;
?>
```

What is the regular expression to find this string in the source code of the $sourceurl?

Comment: Readers are generally very happy to help. However they will generally expect a prior attempt to be included in questions. If you have not done that yet, please do so, and edit it into the post.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
preg_match('~'.preg_quote($string, '~').'~i', $sourceurl, $link);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your link don't need to be find by a Regex in your example.

You can do :

```
$sourceurl = file_get_contents('https://www.facebook.com/PeinadosFacilesRapido/videos/399225660865821/');

if ( stripos($sourceurl, $link))
{

    // do something
}
```

Comment: `$link` is what OP is trying to find in the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

The most reliable way would be to use a HTML parser, but this should work:

```
<?php
    $sourceurl = file_get_contents('https://www.facebook.com/PeinadosFacilesRapido/videos/399225660865821/');

    preg_match('/sd_src:"(.*?)"/s', $sourceurl, $linkArray);

    $link = $linkArray[1];

    echo $link;
```

Comment: Hello ! thanks for your answer but it is throwing some error i just mentioned in the screenshot url(http://prntscr.com/munqx0) and i tried removing '[1]' but it is not working also.

Comment: Hello there I have a query to ask you about finding REG EXP in PHP. Look at this quesion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55059224/can-anyone-solve-this-to-find-reg-ex-in-php and help me to find REG EX. Thank!